# Adding transition to pseudo element (SASS)

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

I am trying to gradually change the background of a div on hover instead of immediately, however I am having trouble applying transition to my pseudo element. This is what I tried -

```
@mixin project-styling($url) {
  background: url($url);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s;

  &:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    content: '';
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}

div {
  @include project-styling('image.png');
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a working code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition needs to be on the pseudo element as well. You also did not include the pseudo element when the div is not being hovered.

```
    @mixin project-styling($url) {
      background: url($url);
      background-size: cover;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: all 2s;

      &::after {
         background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
         content: '';
         width: 400px;
         height: 300px;
         transition: all 2s;
      }

      &:hover::after {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      }
    }

    div {
      @include project-styling('image.png');
    }
```